# Namespace search not finding element

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri, microsoft-dynamics, savon

I'm trying to parse a XML response to process sales orders but the XPath search isn't working.

Here's a snippet of the XML response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <SalesOrderServiceFindResponse xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/services">
            <SalesOrder xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder">
                <DocPurpose>Original</DocPurpose>
                <SenderId>bell</SenderId>
                <SalesTable class="entity">
                    <_DocumentHash>33e9a9be2bcafdb1edde17c4e12d1166</_DocumentHash>
                    <ConsTarget_JP>No</ConsTarget_JP>
                    <CurrencyCode>USD</CurrencyCode>
                    <CustAccount>ANDE01</CustAccount>
                    <CustGroup>Distributo</CustGroup>
                    <CustomsExportOrder_IN>No</CustomsExportOrder_IN>
                    <CustomsShippingBill_IN>No</CustomsShippingBill_IN>
                    <DAXIntegrationId>{5A1B9C05-99DD-4E4E-91F1-2702117CEF98}</DAXIntegrationId>
                    <Deadline>2016-03-31</Deadline>
                    <DeliveryDate>2016-03-01</DeliveryDate>
                    ...
                </SalesTable>
                <SalesTable>
                    ...
                </SalesTable>
            </SalesOrder>
        </SalesOrderServiceFindResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

There are multiple `<SalesTable>` entities that I am trying to get through so I can process the data in an external system.

However, the following does not work:

```
response = client.call(:find, 
        message_tag: :SalesOrderServiceFindRequest,
        message: {
            :query_criteria => {
                :@xmlns => "http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2006/02/documents/QueryCriteria",
                :criteria_element => {
                    :data_source_name => "SalesTable", 
                    :field_name => "CustGroup", 
                    :operator => "Equal",
                    :value1 => "Distributo",
                }
            }
        }
    )
```

This is empty:

```
puts response.xpath("//SalesTable")
```

This is empty too:

```
puts response.xpath("//SalesOrder/SalesTable", "xmlns" => "http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder") # empty
```

So is this:

```
puts response.xpath("//SalesOrder", "xmlns" => "http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder")
```

I don't understand because I can verify that there IS a `SalesTable` element, so it should be found but it's not working.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the namespace prefix in your query. The fact you have used it `xmlns` doesn’t make it apply automatically:

```
response.xpath("//xmlns:SalesOrder", "xmlns" => "http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder")
```

In fact it might be worth using a different prefix, e.g.

```
response.xpath("//so:SalesOrder", "so" => "http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder")
```

Comment: Yes, this is the correct answer. You can read more at [the Nokogiri tutorial on searching](http://www.nokogiri.org/tutorials/searching_a_xml_html_document.html#namespaces).

Comment: The problem is this element isn't namespaced with that prefix. I have no control over what the system replies with because it's a Microsoft Dynamics AIF response. I can't make it add a different namespace in that way.

Comment: It does not work. The tag is `<SalesOrder>` not `<xmlns:SalesOrder>` so it still isn't matching.

Comment: @Oranges13 it doesn’t matter what prefix is used in the original XML, the important part is that the namespace in your query matches the namespace in the document. In the document the element is in the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/dynamics/2008/01/documents/SalesOrder` namespace (because it is a descendent of the `SalesOrder` element that has the `xmlns` attribute set). You need to make sure that in your query you specify the same namespace, and you do that by using a prefix (any prefix, it doesn’t matter) and associating that prefix with the namespace.